# How to connect frontend React code in Amplify to my spring backend API deployed in ElasticBeanstalk?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-amplify

I'm using the fetch method in my React and the endpoint path used is the domain of my EC2 instance `https://my-api.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/` (changed the URL to 'my-api' for obvious reasons).

When I make a direct request on the browser to `https://my-api.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/ping` it works fine. But when doing it from the fetch button on the React app (from the site `https://my-endpoint.bleble.amplifyapp.com/`) I see `(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and no API call was made at all.

I only have my front deployed in Amplify and my backend on Elastic Beanstalk. (The idea is to deploy this app with the minimum required to function)

---

On postman, the backend endpoint works perfectly; is the frontend-backend connection the problem.

---

**ConfigData.json**

```
{
  "AWS_REST_ENDPOINT": "https://my-api.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"
}
```

**Frontend Code**

```
import configData from '../configData.json'

export async function getFitArb(data) {
    const response = await fetch(configData.AWS_REST_ENDPOINT + `/api/arb`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })

    if (!response.ok) {
      if (response.status === 500) {
        return {'resume':[]};
        throw new Error('Server Error');
      } else if (response.status === 404) {
        throw new Error('Resource Not Found');
      } else {
        throw new Error('Unknown Error');
      }
    }

    return await response.json();
}
```

**Backend Controller**

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class ArbController {
    
    private final ArbService arbitrageService;
    private final ConfigurationHolder configurationHolder;
    private final CustomSerializer serializer;


    @PostMapping("/arb")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createArbitrages(@RequestBody Inv inv) throws JsonProcessingException {
```

---

**Tries:**

1. Started pointing to the http endpoint of the backend API (front the React code)
2. Then I saw I needed to use the https one
3. Added the `mode: 'no-cors'`  on the frontend fetch method

None of these worked.

**I expected:** Frontend (from browser) [It's in Amplify service] -> Click on the fetch button -> Request to backend API in ElastickBeanstalk -> Returns response to the frontend -> Reloads browser info